# Use Key File with Application Running on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: node.js, firebase, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use a key file in my Kubernetes application and I can't seem to find an example of this anywhere. I want to use Firebase authentication in my NodeJS backend. When running my application locally I was using the following

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH),
});
```

My initial thought was to create a `secret` from a key file like

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster --zone us-central1-c --project my-project
$ kubectl create secret generic service-account-key \
    --from-file=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH}
```

However, since I am creating a `secret` there is not a path for me to set my `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH` to when running my application in a Kubernetes container. What is the correct method for doing this in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can save the **serviceaccount** file inside the **secret** and mount the secret into the deployment volume.

so the secret will be accessible to deployment's volume and your pod can access it.

for example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
```

you can check out the :

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-case-pod-with-ssh-keys

another example : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-case-dotfiles-in-a-secret-volume

so basic idea is to mount the secret into the volume of the deployment and it will be used by the code.